# Python replacement for ez-ipupdate?

Tags: python

I want to update my dynamic dns entry from behind a NAT, which ez-ipupdate doesn't support. It uses the locally bound ip instead of the external ip address.

My provider, easydns, only explicitly supports the ez-ipupdate solution on my platform, Linux.

Instead of writing a python-based deamon to get the external IP address and put it into the ez-ipupdate config file regularly, I wondered if there was a way to replace the whole thing with a python script. Maybe it would simplify things.

(I could not find any information about this on google, so I'm asking and answering this question here in order to help others.)

Answer (score 0):

It would simplify things indeed. At least for easydns, ez-ipupdate only really performs a simple GET request with Basic HTTP Authentication.

The below code is a starting point. It's been tested, it works. It needs the `requests` and `ipgetter` modules from pypi.

```
import time
import ipgetter
import requests
import datetime
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def update(user, auth_token, hostname, partner="easydns", cache_fn=None):
    if cache_fn is None:
        cache_fn = "/var/cache/ez-ipupdate/default-cache"

    my_ip = ipgetter.myip()

    with open(cache_fn) as fobj:
        secs, ip = fobj.read().strip().split(",")
    if ip == my_ip:
        return "IP doesn't need updating"

    last_update = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(secs))
    diff = datetime.datetime.now() - last_update
    minutes_since_last_update = diff.total_seconds() / 60.0
    if minutes_since_last_update < 4.99:
        return "Too short time since last update..."

    with open(cache_fn, "wb") as fobj:
        fobj.write("{},{}\n".format(int(time.time()), my_ip))

    url = (
       'https://api.cp.easydns.com/dyn/ez-ipupdate.php?action=edit'
       '&myip={address}&partner={partner}&wildcard=OFF&hostname={host}'
       ).format(address=my_ip, partner=partner, host=hostname)

    r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, auth_token))
    return "{} {}".format(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Now just run a script calling the update functions regularly, e.g. using `crontab -e` and adding this line:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.py
```